# How can I force Drupal to load all taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, 6

On a site that heavily uses Drupal core's taxonomy, we are encountering serious problems when editing content: Already entered taxonomy terms are not properly loaded into the node editing form; fields that should contain values are rendered empty; when the nodes are saved, the terms are lost. So this is *not* a display issue.

Please note: *Some* terms are not loaded into the node editing form. We know exactly which terms *should* be there because a View displays the terms in a structured fashion.

I am aware that Drupal inherits multiple issues with large forms from PHP; for example, large user permission screens are not being saved in Drupal, because PHP has a default value for 'max_input_vars' of '1000'; by increasing this value, e.g. to '1500', Drupal becomes able to save user permissions again. We'Re supecting something similar with the node editing screens. However, in our case, values are not even inserted from the database into the node editing form, so it's totally unclear where to even start looking for a solution.

The environment:

- Drupal 6 (Pressflow)
- Around 110,000 nodes
- 24 vocabularies with >  100,000 terms

Also noteworthy: The problem with incomplete node editing forms is not limited to taxonomy terms; it sporadically also applies to other form elements like attach images.

Are there any PHP configuration values that could cause this misbehaviour or does Form API have any hard limits in redard not the size of node editing forms (e.g. number of form elements per form, memory limits per node editing form)?

Comment: Do you have any custom code in relation to your node forms?

Comment: This question appears offtopic because it's a bugreport for PressFlow. Bugs belong to issue queue, not here. All terms should be loaded, we are literally unable to debug your site and tell why they are not for you. Try to use devel module, identify offending query. Maybe then we'll be able to help.

Comment: @rooby: No, we do not use any custom code on the node editing forms. Also, the default forms are not overriden by a contributed module like Panels.
1   
   
 This question appears offtopic because it's a bugreport for PressFlow. Bugs belong to issue queue, not here. All terms should be loaded, we are literally unable to debug your site and tell why they are not for you. Try to use devel module, identify offending query. Maybe then we'll be able to help. –  Mołot 6 hours ago

Comment: @Mołot: This problem is not a Pressflow issue; you can exchange Pressflow with a vanilla Drupal core and it shows the same behaviour. Why do you think that there is an "offending query"?

Comment: Are the taxonomy terms being edited using SELECT elements? This could simply be a browser issue if you are trying to load huge forms. Are the forms complete if you pull the page source using wget or similar?

Comment: @user153878 if it is a bug in Drupal, it only changes where you should report it, not the fact that bugreports does not belong here. And if not all terms are shown, *probably* some query fails to get them from database, or some loop fails to get everything from query. Either way, there ought to be this special faulty query we need to concentrate on.

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong: This is definitely a valid point. I know that Drupal sites can become inaccessible for editing when using Opera and 'image' module with 10k+ image nodes (Opera takes 20+ minutes to load editing forms; Firefox takes about a minute). However, to check with wget, I have to figure how to authenticate (for editing a node; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication) through Varnish (which rejects bots an downloaders with an HTTP error 418, http://www.error418.org/).

Comment: If you have access to the server console, this should be trivial: just fetch directly from the web server rather than via Varnish. Otherwise could you get round the Varnish issue by faking a user-agent string?

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong: Yes, I have shell access, but wget still receives an "418: I'm a teapot" from Varnish. And yes, wget can theoretically fake accept header, user-agent and the referer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182553/sites-not-accepting-wget-user-agent-header) + user auth. That results in a string like "wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user={user}&password={password}' --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --referrer {domain.tld} http://{site.tld/user}" (but this syntax won't work).

Comment: You should be able to bypass Varnish and fetch from Apache (or whatever) directly, that was my point. You just need to use whatever port the web server is listening on. So eg http://localhost:8000/path or http://virtual.example.com:8080/path etc.